# Edit Cluster in Android Maps utlis in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, markerclusterer

I am trying out the cluster images given in http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/...

I have set the maps for my App clustering is happening properly, but I would like to make some changes like can I move the number of images clustered in the top. Like the screenshot given below:

[image]

The black box is from the library I would like to have a blue box in the top and with white text in the center. Is this possible? If so, what should be done where should I start?

Can somebody guide me on this? I mean is this possible?

Thanks!